# WebApi HttpPut is working fine in localhost. In server it not working. It throws 403

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, jquery-ajax

Created a web api [HttpPut] method. When testing from local host, data is getting updated. When access the api(hosted in nginx - aws ec2) it throws 403 error. This api is developed in asp.net core web-api.

This api is called through JQuery ajax.

**Controller:**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EventSchedulerController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(500)]
    [Route("UpdateEvent")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEvent(EventSchedulerDTO evt)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(evt.Id))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        try
        {
            var existingEventData = _db.EventSchedulers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == evt.Id);
            existingEventData.Title = evt.Title;
            existingEventData.Description = evt.Description;
            existingEventData.EventStartDateTime = evt.EventStartDateTime;
            existingEventData.EventEndDateTime = evt.EventEndDateTime;

            _db.EventSchedulers.Update(existingEventData);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(new { Status = "Success", Message = "Data successfully updated" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#btnSaveSchedule").click(function () {
    var eventSchedulerData = {
        "id": $(this).data("event-id"),
        "title": $("#txtTitle").val(),
        "description": $("#txtDescription").val(),
        "eventStartDateTime": new Date($("#txtStartDateTime").val()).toISOString(),
        "eventEndDateTime": new Date($("#txtEndDateTime").val()).toISOString(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/EventScheduler/UpdateEvent',
        type: 'put',
        data: JSON.stringify(eventSchedulerData),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove [Authorize] from your controller or you need to add  a token to your ajax request.

After this try the code:

```
$("#btnSaveSchedule").click(function () {
    var eventSchedulerData = {
        id: $(this).data("event-id"),
        title: $("#txtTitle").val(),
        description: $("#txtDescription").val(),
        eventStartDateTime: new Date($("#txtStartDateTime").val()).toISOString(),
        eventEndDateTime: new Date($("#txtEndDateTime").val()).toISOString(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/EventScheduler/UpdateEvent',
        type: 'PUT',
        data: eventSchedulerData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        }
    });
});
```